# Is anyone familiar with the name of this plot?

Tags: python, r, plot

I was wondering what this plot in Winning Eleven Games is called:

[image: some plot]

Is there a way to create it using Python or R? Thank you anyone :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a so-called Spiderweb or Radar chart. Highcharts has a great implementation of it (https://www.highcharts.com/demo/polar-spider), which you can access in R using the `highcharteR` package: http://jkunst.com/highcharter/highcharts-api.html

Comment: I see.. a great API indeed :), thankyou for the references

Answer (score 1):

The name is Radar chart basicly.

In `R` you should use the `fmsb` package and the `radarchart` function.

Below an example:

```
library(fmsb)
data <- as.data.frame(matrix( sample( 2:20 , 10 , replace=T) , ncol=10))
colnames(data) <- c("math" , "english" , "biology" , "music" , "R-coding", "data-viz" , "french" , "physic", "statistic", "sport" )
data <- rbind(rep(20,10) , rep(0,10) , data)
radarchart( data  , axistype=1 , 
    pcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.9) , pfcol=rgb(0.2,0.5,0.5,0.5) , plwd=4 , 
    cglcol="grey", cglty=1, axislabcol="grey", caxislabels=seq(0,20,5), cglwd=0.8,
    vlcex=0.8)
```

Here if you want to [deep](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/radarchart/radarchart.pdf)

Instead in `Python` you should use `plotly`.

```
import plotly.express as px
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(dict(
    r=[1, 5, 2, 2, 3],
    theta=['processing cost','mechanical properties','chemical stability',
           'thermal stability', 'device integration']))
fig = px.line_polar(df, r='r', theta='theta', line_close=True)
fig.show()
```

Here if you want to [deep](https://plotly.com/python/radar-chart/)

Comment: Thankyou for the examples reference @slowLearning, Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

This is called radar(Excel has it with this name)/spider/polygon chart. there is a package named radar in python you can use. And you can find a great way to draw one yourself with python [in this link](https://python-graph-gallery.com/391-radar-chart-with-several-individuals/).

you just need to replace your values in the sample code